# Why does H2O integrate TensorFlow via Spark instead of directly?

Tags: java, apache-spark, tensorflow, h2o, sparkling-water

I really like H2O especially because you can deploy the built models easily into any Java / JVM application... This is also my goal for TensorFlow: Build models and then run them in Java applications.

H2O uses Spark (Sparking Water) "in the middle" when using TensorFlow by running TensorFlow on the distributed Spark nodes. I learned this (hopefully correctly) in a [H2O demo video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=62TFK641gG8).

**Why do you not integrate TensorFlow (and others like MXNet) directly with H2O, but instead go through Apache Spark?**

Frameworks like TensorFlow itself allow [distributed training](https://www.tensorflow.org/deploy/distributed), so why use Spark "in the middle"? Doesn't this increase complexity a lot (and no need for it in many scenarios)?

For example, Google built [Scikit Flow](http://www.kdnuggets.com/2016/02/scikit-flow-easy-deep-learning-tensorflow-scikit-learn.html) (Scikit-learn + TensorFlow)to allow easy usage of TensorFlow to build models.

Especially for smaller data sets and / or simpler use cases, this seems to be the easier option that using Spark in the middle? If I understand correctly, you could also use this model in Java then via [TensorFlow4Java](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_java).

I want to leverage H2O much more in future projects and scenarios (like in the past, see e.g. here where I [applied a H2O model to real time applications using Apache Kafka and its Streams API](https://www.slideshare.net/KaiWaehner/apache-kafka-streams-machine-learning-deep-learning)). 
Though, **I am not sure why I need the "overhead" of Spark for building models with H2O and TensorFlow** (especially for smaller data sets and / or simple scenarios where a "small neural network" might be good enough?

Answer (score 1):

That is an old tutorial, which was made before distributed Tensorflow was released. At that time this was the easiest way to "integrate"/"distribute" it (by simply running TF on each worker node and then averaging the coefficients on the driver node).

Since then we have released [project DeepWater](https://www.h2o.ai/deep-water/) which integrates several DL frameworks (TF, MXNet, Caffee) with H2O. This one doesn't require Spark, all you need to do (if you're running a linux machine) is to download H2O [from here](https://www.h2o.ai/download/) (`H2O with GPU-Enabled Machine Learning`) and run it. If you're running MacOS or Windows you'd have to build both DeepWater and H2O yourself as we don't provide those yet.

As a disclaimer: deepwater currently runs only on a single node, as none of the mentioned frameworks have Java APIs for distribution (for example TF only has Python API for that). I'm working on a distributed version but for now it's not really a #1 priority.

Comment: This clarifies things... I was not aware that DeepWater is NOT running on Spark!

Comment: @KaiWähner to clarify - the tutorial above doesn't use DeepWater. Also deepwater can also run on Spark via SparklingWater but only if there's 1 worker, which is a pretty rare Spark usecase. We'd love to hear from the community if making a distributed version of DeepWater would be useful (we'd need actual use-cases and not only "sure" :-)).